# Network stuttering (rubberband issue)?

Tags: battlefield-4

On countless servers (like 50% of that I join), I get a network stutter (rubberband) issue. All these servers are around ~30 ping to me. When I asked in chat, they said it's a problem with DICE.

What exactly is the issue here, and how can I resolve it so I'm not getting this rubberband issue on various servers that I have under 40ms ping on?

Comment: You should try to see if there's a connection between the server host (the company providing the service) and the stutters. If there's a connection, avoid those who have the issue.

Comment: Same is happening to me since yesterday. Never was a problem before, only crashes ;)

Comment: Interestingly, whenever I test a server for its ping, I always get "10 ms" as answer, even when I'm obviously lagging.